# SignlaR hub instance doesn't created when testing by nunit

Tags: c#, signalr, nunit, resharper

I have SinglaR hub class "MyHub" and a .net client class that connects to it successfully in runtime. however when i'm testing the client with nunit test it doesn't connect, I've debugged the test and find that hub instance doesn't created by SinglaR's hub activator class.
I'm using Resharper nunit runner for running test.

Here is my hub class structure, i've remove method's body for simplicity.

```
[HubName("myHub")]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyHub));




    #region MyRegion

    #region Connection Methods


    public MyHub()
    {

    }


    private static int c;
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {

    }

    private string UserNameConnectionId
    {

    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {

         }
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool b)
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {

        }
    }

    private void LogUserActivity(string userName, string activity)
    {

    }

    #endregion

    //Live controls invoke this Method to send their required data and also their ConnectionId
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="liveControlsInfo"></param>
    public Task UpdateLiveControlsInfo(LiveControlInfo[] liveControlsInfo)
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {

        }
    }



    public string GetValue()
    {
        return "SignalR Rox!";
    }


    public void Acknowledge()
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            }
        }
    }

    #endregion


    }


}
```

here is HubWinClient class

```
public class HubWinClient
{
    private readonly string _userName;
    public int ServerPort { get; set; }
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (HubWinClient));
    protected int HubLogCounter = 0;
    private HubConnection connection;

    private bool moduleStarted;
    private IHubProxy myHub;

    public HubWinClient(int serverPort, string userName= "Windows Hub Client", bool tryConnect=false)
    {
        _userName = userName;
        ServerPort = serverPort;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        ConnectToHub();
        moduleStarted = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        DisconnectFromHub();
        moduleStarted = false;
    }

    public void ConnectToHub()
    {
        ConnectToHub(false);
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ConnectingToHub = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ConnectedToHub = delegate { };

    /// <summary>
    /// callback event called by hubhost
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<int> LogSentToHub = delegate { };

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DisonnectedFromHub = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> HubConnectionError = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> HubInvokeError = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> HubInvokeSuccess = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> NotConnectedToSentLog = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<LogMessage> DataRecivedFromHub = delegate { };

    /// <summary>
    ///     connects HunNotifier to Hun in order to ListenerMessage passing can be done
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reconnect"></param>
    private void ConnectToHub(bool reconnect)
    {
        //This url will not point to a specific connection. But will instead point to the root of your site=root of hub server.

        string hubAddress = "http://localhost:" + ServerPort;
        connection = new HubConnection(hubAddress, new Dictionary<string, string>{{"UserName", _userName } });

        ConnectingToHub(this, new EventArgs());
        if (reconnect)
            logger.InfoFormat("HubWinClient reconnecting to HubHost @ {0}...", hubAddress);
        else
            logger.InfoFormat("HubWinClient connecting to HubHost @ {0}...", hubAddress);

        myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");

        myHub.On("joined", joined);
        myHub.On("rejoined", rejoined);
        myHub.On("leaved", leaved);
        myHub.On<LogMessage>("addData", addData);
        myHub.On<int>("LogSentToWeb", LogSentToWeb);
        connection.StateChanged += change =>
        {
            var a = change;
            var b = 10;
            var a1 = connection.LastError;
            var b2 = connection.Proxy;
        };
        try
        {
            connection.Start();

        }
        catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
        {
            Exception exception = aggregateException.InnerException;
            logger.Error("HubWinClient connection to HubHost exception...", exception);
            HubConnectionError(this, new MyEventArgs {Exception = exception});
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.Error("HubWinClient connection to HubHost exception...", exception);
            HubConnectionError(this, new MyEventArgs {Exception = exception});
        }
    }

    public void DisconnectFromHub()
    {
        connection.Stop();
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     when hub notifier connected to hub, hub invoke this method to inform connection success.
    /// </summary>
    public void joined()
    {
        var liveControlInfo = new LiveControlInfo
        {
            LiveControlType = LiveControlType.mainClient
        };
        // myHub.Invoke("AddLiveControl", liveControlInfo).Wait();
        // logger.Info("HubWinClient joined");
        ConnectedToHub(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     when hub notifier reconnected to hub, hub invoke this method to inform reconnection success.
    /// </summary>
    public void rejoined()
    {
        logger.Info("HubWinClient rejoined");

    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     when hub notifier disconnect from hub, hub invoke this method to inform disconnection.
    /// </summary>
    public void leaved()
    {
        logger.Info("HubWinClient disconnected");
        DisonnectedFromHub(this, new EventArgs());
    }


    public void addData(LogMessage logMessage)
    {

        DataRecivedFromHub(this, logMessage);
    }

    public event EventHandler<LogMessage> OnSendingLogToHub = delegate { };

    /// <summary>
    ///     called by HubClientMoudle when it's ApplyLogReceived are invoked by WCF service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logMessage"></param>
    public void SendToHub(LogMessage logMessage)
    {

        OnSendingLogToHub(this, logMessage);
        if (!moduleStarted) return;

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
            ConnectToHub(true);
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ||
                Math.Abs((logMessage.Log.ArrivalDateTime - DateTime.Now).Ticks) < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).Ticks)
            {
                try
                {
                    Task task = myHub.Invoke("send", logMessage);
                    task.Wait(5000);
                    logger.Debug("Send log success");
                    HubInvokeSuccess(this, new EventArgs());
                }

                catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
                {
                    Exception exception = aggregateException.InnerException;
                    logger.Error("Send log Exceotion!", exception);
                    HubInvokeError(this, new MyEventArgs {Exception = exception});
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    logger.Error("Send log Exceotion!", exception);
                    HubInvokeError(this, new MyEventArgs {Exception = exception});
                }
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Warn("Log arrival date time is not less than DateTime.Now+30 minutues");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            logger.Warn("HubWinClient not connected to send log");
            NotConnectedToSentLog(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     when Hub receives log from HubWinClient, calls this method to inform send success
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="log"></param>
    public void LogSentToWeb(int logId)
    {
        logger.Debug("Call back from Hub: send success");
        LogSentToHub(this, logId);
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
    [Category("Integration")]
public class HubWinClientTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestConnection()
    {
        //arrange
        const int port = 4000;
        HubHost hubHost = new HubHost(port);
        HubWinClient hubWinClient = new HubWinClient(port,"mvc app client");

        bool clientConnected = false;
        bool clientDisconnected = false;
        bool hubInvokeError = false;

        hubWinClient.ConnectedToHub += (sender, args) => { clientConnected = true; };
        hubWinClient.DisonnectedFromHub += (sender, args) => { clientDisconnected = true; };
        hubWinClient.HubInvokeError += (sender, args) => { hubInvokeError = true; };

        //act
        hubHost.Start();
        hubWinClient.Start();

        //assert
        var constrain = Is.True.After(10000, 100);
        Assert.That(() => clientConnected, constrain);

        //act
        hubWinClient.SendToHub(new LogMessage());

        //assert
        var constrain2 = Is.True.After(2000, 100);
        Assert.That(() => hubInvokeError == false, constrain2);

        // act
        hubWinClient.DisconnectFromHub();

        //  assert
        var constrain1 = Is.True.After(2000, 100);
        Assert.That(() => clientDisconnected, constrain1);

        hubHost.Stop();


    }
}
```

For some reason when i run my the test by resharper nunit runner, hub instance does created and my test fails. i think it's related to Resharper's and how it create test environment (i'e process creation and such stuff).

Any ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't await connection start. It might be that you are trying to send hub requests before the connection finished starting. You should `await` async calls.

Comment: @Pawel, awaiting connection.Start() doesn't makes any difference.